# AsyncTask doInBackGround is not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've created an AsyncTask for my app but doinbackground method is not called upon onpreexecute. Here is my code:

```
public class NewProductActivity extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "Sending data...", true);

    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            boolean added = dbo.addDataToDB(name, pass);

            Log.d("1234rrr", name +" "+pass);

            return added;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result){
            Toast.makeText(context, "successfully added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "failed to add data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            new NewProductActivity(UserName.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString(), this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        else
            new NewProductActivity(UserName.getText().toString(),Password.getText().toString(),this).execute();
```

But the app is stuck on onpreexecute. By the way I have only one asynctask. Can anyone help me with this situation? Thanks!

Edit:

I've realized that when I put the log message in the first line of doinbackground I get the message. I'm guessing the problem is with addDataToDB function. Here is the code for addDataToDB:

```
public boolean addDataToDB(String name, String pass){
        try{
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.sample.com/phpfilelocation/insertData.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks fine just thinking why onPreExecute method does not have override annotation? And r u able to see the progress dialog when u run the app?

Comment: yes I see the progress diialog but it is stuck on "sending data" .

Comment: Will suggest put a Log message in the first line of doInBackground may be u r going to the method but addDataToDb is not working. Or a better approach will be to do debugging by putting break point in the method.

Comment: Given doInBackground is working properly, try wrapping `progressDialog.dismiss();` like this
`if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }`

Comment: I've put  a log message in the first line of do InBackGround but nothing seems to appear on the logcat

Comment: I've editeed my question